# How can I get URLs from Oddsportal?

Tags: python, web-scraping

How can I get all the URLs from this particular link: https://www.oddsportal.com/results/#soccer

For every URL on this page, there are multiple pages e.g. the first link of the page:

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/

leads to the below page as an example:

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/

-> https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/page/2/...

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2019/results/

-> https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2019/results/#/page/2/...

I would ideally like to code in python as I am pretty comfortable with it (more than other languages through not at all close to what I can call as comfortable)
[image: inspect element]
and

After clicking on the link:

[image: Inspect element]

When I go to inspect element, I can see tha the links can be scraped however I am very new to it.

Please help

Comment: Please post your code. What did you try and where are you stuck ?

Comment: Right now, I am manually copying every URL on the page and creating a list. hence, I am not sure what code I can post here

Comment: Are you new to web-scraping ?

Comment: @Ram Yes. Very new. I have created a code that scrapes all the data 'in a URL'. But, to get all the URLs I need help. Because of the For loops and all the attributes, I am unable to get my head around it.

Comment: @Ram If I can post existing code to scrape data from a URL here, would it help?

Answer (score 0):

I have extracted the URLs from the main page that you mentioned.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/results/#soccer'
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

base_url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com'

a = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'foo': 'f'})

# This set will have all the URLs of the main page
s = set()

for i in a:
    s.add(base_url + i['href'])
```

Since you are new to web-scraping I suggest you to go through these.

- `Beautiful Soup` - Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.

> Docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

- `requests` - Requests is an elegant and simple HTTP library for Python.

> Docs: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

- `Selenium` - Selenium is an umbrella project for a range of tools and libraries that enable and support the automation of web browsers.

> Docs: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: This is closer to what I want. The above code is getting all URLs available on the page. I would like only for 'soccer' this is because extra data will cause problems. The code is scrpaing all URL including other sports such as handball and tennis, etc.

Comment: Also, thank you for the links, I will go through all of them

Comment: Also, for every of that URL, there are many pages e.g. for https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/national-league/results/, there are URLs i.e. https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/national-league-2019-2020/results/ and https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/national-league-2018-2019/results/, etc. How do I get them?